# Java Binding Abstract class not being generated

Tags: binding, xamarin, xamarin.android

> Error CS0234: The type or namespace name `IBitmap' does not exist in the namespace`Com.Sushi.Hangover'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

I have an Android binding project which has classes that are inheriting from multiple interfaces but these interfaces are not been generated and thus all of the public classes that depend upon them are failing to bind.

#### Java Class:

```
abstract interface Bitmap
{
   ~~~ (methods removed)
}
```

#### api.xml:

```
<interface abstract="true" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="Bitmap" static="false" visibility="">
```

As you can see the `visibility` of this interface is not set to `public` and thus no C# code is generated, but there are public classes begin generated that depend on this interface:

```
public partial class DrawableDesign : global::Com.Sushi.Hangover.IBitmap {
```

The binding is aware of the interface as it transforming the interface name from `Bitmap` to `IBitmap`.

> Is there any way to force these interfaces to be created without going back the Java code and changing these interfaces to public to get them into the `api.xml` as `visibility="public"`?

Note: I am on stable channel (Xamarin.Android Version: 6.0.3.5) as this client does not have Alpha/Beta access

Comment: Can you post a sample jar somewhere I can play with. Has been too long since I've worked with Java and packing jars.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Thanks for the offer. Closed source from the client's partner. They recently made major changes to the source and broke the metadata/enummethods/enumfields files (250+ lines of transforms that made me crosseyed the first time....). Client is rolling back to an older (working) version of Xamarin.Android and their Java code in order to get customer changes release to Google Play... :-/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've written a smallish guide on this topic that might help in certain areas: https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb

In short, you could potentially try changing the visibility like @Cheesebaron has mentioned already: https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb#class-visibility (Replace /class with interface or read the common paths)

Otherwise you can potentially try to add the node from scratch: https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb#adding-types

For a more exact answer, I believe we would need to see the respective .jar/.aar and the current Bindings project.

Comment: Sweet, "Awesome gist" ;-) The `<add-node>` works (still not sure why setting the visibility public via the `attr` does not work in this case, I've used it before) I've done 3 of the interfaces via `add-node` and got one of the main classes to bind properly again and it works fine in the Android app, only 52 more :-/ (I already had the `sharpie` equivalent library working so at least no head-banging over ObjC today). Not sure what the client is going to do (their budget is tight), but at least they have a working option that they can use if desired. Thanks again.

Comment: Did you ensure that the node was being detected/hit with the respective command? (Diaglostic Build Output is your friend here). A message along the lines of "no matched nodes" would indicate a failure.

Comment: Yes it is.. no problems with the class' xpath... It works fine in the older `.jar` and older Xamarin version. This new `.jar` has a bunch of new reference `.jar`s  that of course I had to add, newer JDK/javac used, but the `.jar` decompiles fine, they are using interfaces that `extends` other now, but I bind other jars that do that... Well, its almost adult beverage time anyway ;-)

Comment: Ah well in that case there could be other things going on. (i.e. JDK version, API levels, references, etc). Anyway if `<add-node>` is the easiest workaround then it's probably 5pm somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

In your binding library inside of the Transforms/Metadata.xml file you can change the visibility by adding the following line:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.sushi.hangover']/interface[@name='IBitmap']" name="visibility">public</attr>
```

Given that the package name in Java world is `com.sushi.hangover` and interface name is `IBitmap`.

You can read some more about the [format of attr in the GAPI mono documentation.](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/gapi/#metadata) There is also some nice [bindings documentation in the Xamarin Docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata/).

Comment: Thanks but just tried that, no change, still does not produce the C#-based interface classes, I been through GAPI many times ;-)