# Xamarin Binding Jar gives error: does not implement inherited abstract member AsyncTask.DoInBackground(params Object[])

Tags: java, xamarin, android-asynctask, xamarin.android

I want to use a .jar file that I have with my Xamarin.Android project.

After I create the binding project and try to build, I get this error:

`obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Acrcloud.Rec.Sdk.Utils.ACRCloudGetIPAddressAsyncTask.cs(23,23): Error CS0534: 'ACRCloudGetIPAddressAsyncTask' does not implement inherited abstract member 'AsyncTask.DoInBackground(params Object[])' (CS0534)`

Using a decompiler, I checked the contents of `ACRCloudGetIPAddressAsyncTask` and found this:

```
package com.acrcloud.rec.sdk.utils;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class ACRCloudGetIPAddressAsyncTask
extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{
    private static final String TAG = "ACRCloudAsynGetIPAddressTask";

    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        String ip = "";
        try
        {
            InetAddress x = InetAddress.getByName(params[0]);

            ip = x.getHostAddress();
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            ip = "";
        }
        catch (Exception e2)
        {
            ip = "";
        }
       return ip;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(String ip)
  {
     super.onPreExecute();
     ACRCloudLogger.d("ACRCloudAsynGetIPAddressTask", ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  " + ip);
     com.acrcloud.rec.sdk.recognizer.ACRCloudRecognizerRemoteImpl.serverIP = ip;
  }
}
```

Why do I even need to implement `DoInBackground(params Object[])`? The generated C# code implemented `protected virtual unsafe string DoInBackground (params  string[] @params)` to match what's in the Java code...I don't know a lot about Java so I'm probably missing something...any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can check this great post: [Approaching a Xamarin.Android Bindings Case](https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb#approaching-a-xamarinandroid-bindings-case), by checking the [Adding Types](https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb#adding-types) part, it uses `<add-node>` when we want to add a class, change a constructor, or switch a generic type.

For your lib, you can open the `Metadata.xml` under the `Transforms` folder, and then add this code:

```
<add-node path="/api/package[@name='com.acrcloud.rec.sdk.utils']">
  <class abstract="false" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="ACRCloudLocalRecognizerInitAsyncTask" static="true" visibility="public" extends="java.lang.Object">
  </class>

  <class abstract="false" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="ACRCloudGetIPAddressAsyncTask" static="true" visibility="public" extends="java.lang.Object">
  </class>
</add-node>
```

Then it can be successfully compiled, but I didn't test to reference this lib to Xamarin.Android project, you may need further research for using this lib. Anyway, that post helps a lot.

You can also check the similar case on SO: [Java Binding Abstract class not being generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36648926/java-binding-abstract-class-not-being-generated).

Comment: It works, but I don't understand why. You add a node in the `Metadata.xml` that makes these classes extend `java.lang.Object` instead of `AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>` ...how does this help? I know it does (because it works now) but I don't understand why?

Comment: @Darius, The abstract member is `AsyncTask.DoInBackground(params Object[])`, it changes the classes, so they don't inherit from the old class which need to implement this member, so I said, you may need further research if you want to use the original class, but if not, you can also remove it.

Comment: Extending the class from Object does compile. But I need AsyncTask's execute method. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user4442171 I second this comment. The issue seems to be that in Java you're allowed to implement a method expecting "Object... params" by using "String... params" instead. This isn't allowed in C#, so the generated DoInBackground(params string[] @params) method does not count as an implementation of AsyncTask.DoInBackground.

The proper fix here would be to change the parameter type in C#, but I'm unable to figure out how to do that. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
<add-node path="/api/package[@name='yourpPackageName']">
   <class abstract="false" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="YourClassName" static="true" visibility="public" extends="java.lang.Object"> </class>
```

Comment: A bit of additional information would significantly improve this answer. Also, there were two pieces to the question, and at best this answer only addresses one of them.

Comment: Point to be noted KevinO Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The other answers use a workaround that will only work in some cases. If you need the generated class to still extend AsyncTask, you can do this instead:

I was able to modify the method signature of DoInBackground to work correctly:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='$NAMESPACE']/class[@name='$CLASS']/method[@name='doInBackground' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String...']]" name="managedOverride">override</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='$NAMESPACE']/class[@name='$CLASS']/method[@name='doInBackground' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String...']]" name="final">true</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='$NAMESPACE']/class[@name='$CLASS']/method[@name='doInBackground' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String...']]/parameter[1]" name="managedType">params Java.Lang.Object[]</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='$NAMESPACE']/class[@name='$CLASS']/method[@name='doInBackground' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String...']]" name="managedReturn">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
```

The first two lines change virtual to override, the third line changes the parameter type and the fourth line changes the return type.