# Binding java lib to xamarin.android. How to change EventHandler declaration name from meta.xml which throws error code CS0102?

Tags: xamarin.android

```
Severity Code Description Project Path File Line Column Suppression State

Error CS0102 The type 'IOnReceiverListenerImplementor' already contains a definition for 'LcdDisplayHandler'
```

Error says "Class which required to acccess is internal sealed"

```
 [global::Android.Runtime.Register ("mono/com/idtechproducts/device/OnReceiverListenerImplementor")]
    internal sealed partial class IOnReceiverListenerImplementor : global::Java.Lang.Object, IOnReceiverListener {

public EventHandler<LcdDisplayEventArgs> LcdDisplayHandler;
}
```

I need to change name of "LcdDisplayHandler" , Please any Suggestion appreciate.

Comment: Maybe it can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36651955/2889347

Comment: Thanks I'll taka a look